# Rule Inheritance for Windows 2008 Firewall Management With Group Policies

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-firewall

When defining new firewall rules with Group Policies in Windows Server 2008:

- Does adding a single rule to allow traffic disable all other rules that were present locally on the client computer?
- Does it inherit on a individual rule basis.  For example does a single rule over ride a single rule on the client computer (or maybe the other way?)
- Does this behavior depend on some base setting?

Also, any other gotchas when starting out with this would be appreciated if they pop into your head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GPO rules are merged (by default) to local rules. Rules where local and GPO conflict, GPO wins.

I haven't had any problems with it; but I meticulously planned each setting and rule in my Firewall GPOs, being sure to fully understand the implications of each setting before touching it.