# Windows Server 2008 and port 80

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, firewall, http

I'm having an issue with my Windows Server 2008. I can successfuly connect to it with FTP(port 21), remote desktop(whatever the port number is), https but not with simple http or port 80, from the outside of my LAN.

Is there some settings I don't know about regarding this special port on the firewall or on IIS7?

For your information, I can connect to port 80 as long as I'm on the same LAN, but as soon as the request come from the outside, I get nothing...

Please help
Thank you

Comment: I know some ISPs block this port, but I can't imagine they'd allow HTTPS and FTP but not HTTP. 

Have you verified there's nothing on your hardware firewall or router blocking port 80?

Did you tell IIS to listen on the correct IP address?

Perhaps you could try binding it to a non-standard port and then try to access it from an external source.

Comment: It sounds crazy, but that's exactly what the local ISP does, to residential customers at least. They allow all ports inbound except 25 and 80... *sigh*

Comment: @Kyle That's what I had to do when I was with Cox. (worst company name ever :P) Verizon doesn't seem to block it though, so yay. I found that it was pointless to use a nonstandard port since they block them at work anyway :( It has to do with their service agreement: I think most ISPs have a "no server" clause ... they want you to use their business products. It's dumb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, if you are using an ISP's residential plan, there's a good chance they're blocking port 80. Try using a nonstandard, or even just 8080, and see if you can get to it from an external source.

Comment: To be clear, are you accessing this from outside your network, or are there other private networks you've tried to access from?

Answer (score 1):

Could be the firewall on the server, you have the "Scope" option in Windows firewall, usually set to localnet.. which you would need to change to any.

You could read this post in regards to windows app firewalls: [is 2003 Server Firewall appropriate](https://serverfault.com/questions/21841/is-windows-2003-firewall-appropriate-for-a-web-server)
Or this [Windows Firewalls + GPO's](https://serverfault.com/questions/173955/rule-inheritance-for-windows-2008-firewall-management-with-group-policies) As you might be setting your firewall via GPO (If you are in a domain)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like there is some ACL between your connection to the Internet and to the server. Perhaps ask whoever administers your firewall to double check the policy to that machine?